# Regex to validate exact 8 or exact 14 character

Tags: java, regex, validation

I have to validate date & datetime in a string in Java.

So the string can have either exact 8 characters (ddMMyyyy) or exact 14 character (ddMMyyyyHHmmss)

I have developed a below REGEX:

```
^(?<scanDate>[^_]{8,14})_(?<branchID>[^_]{6})_(?<productCode>[0-9\\s+()]+)\\.[^.]+$
```

The first group is to be validated for above condition, my regex will validate minimum 8 to maximum 14 characters.

How can I achieve above REGEX condition ?

Thanks,
Suvojit

Comment: `.{8}(.{6})?` should do the trick

Comment: `(\\d{8}|\\d{14})`?

Comment: Can you form the regex in my above pattern ?

Comment: Why don't you try to incorporate the suggestions into your regex instead?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use regular expressions for validating dates with or without times in Java. You’ll get finer validation if you try to parse it as a date or date-time, and the reader will understand much more easily what you’re up to. Look into classes `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`.